# Convert string date to NSDate

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am doing simple string to date and vice versa conversion in my app but string is not converting properly to NSDate in iOS6 only in other versions of iOS it is working as expected.

Following is my code.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM, yyyy EEEE"];
    [df setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

    NSLog(@"String From Date : %@",[df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);

    NSDate *today = [df dateFromString:@"29 January, 2014 Wednesday"];
    NSLog(@"Date : %@",today);
    NSLog(@"Date From String : %@",[df stringFromDate:today]);
```

My output in iOS 6.0 is :

```
String From Date : 29 January, 2014 Wednesday
Date : 1999-12-28 18:30:00 +0000
Date From String : 29 December, 1999 Wednesday
```

My Output in iOS7 is :

```
String From Date : 29 January, 2014 Wednesday
Date : 2014-01-28 18:30:00 +0000
Date From String : 29 January, 2014 Wednesday
```

I have spend much time on searching the date conversion but this is something strange issue i am getting. Can any one help me out with this issue….

Thanks for your support.

Comment: `NSDateFormatter` on iOS 6 doesn't seem to like the `EEEE` in last position, one workaround is to use `"EEEE dd MMMM, yyyy"` or don't parse the `EEEE` part at all when going from `NSString` to `NSDate`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem of iOS6 is in the data formatter style  ,all what you have to do is to replace that line

```
[df setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM, yyyy EEEE"];
```

with that one

```
[df setDateFormat:@"EEEE dd MMMM, yyyy"];
```